# SQL to combine two rows and aggregate

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a SQL query on the below table where first two row need to merge and give output as 10 ||20 ||100.

```
from_id to_id duration
10 20 50
20 10 50
10 30 80
20 40 50
20 40 60
```

need below output

```
from_id to_id total_duration
10 20 100
10 30 80
20 40 110
```

I tried like below but not getting the correct output.

```
select from_id,to_id,sum(total_duration) from table group by from_id,to_id;

from_id to_id total_duration
10 20 50
20 10 50
10 30 80
20 40 110
```

Comment: Where is row 20 - 10 - 50 disappearing in your expected output? Without any description its just pure guessing about what your logic is supposed to be.

Comment: Yep,  James Z is right. I suppose I guessed correctly in my answer, but this is something that you should clarify in your request. It doesn't suffice to say "I need below output", we need to know by what rules you get to that output.

Comment: You should also mention what to do with `NULL` values (if your columns are nullable).

Answer (score 1):

You want to treat the tuples (10,20) and (20,10) as the same tuple. In order to do so, order them with `LEAST` and `GREATEST`:

```
select 
  least(from_id, to_id) as id1,
  greatest(from_id, to_id) as id2,
  sum(total_duration)
from table
group by least(from_id, to_id), greatest(from_id, to_id)
order by least(from_id, to_id), greatest(from_id, to_id);
```